# Is there a built-in way to record Mac screen in macOS screen just like iOS?

Tags: macos, screen-capture, recording, screen-recording

As shown in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhsOrAQx8ms&t=27s) video, one can easily make a screen recoding of an iOS device (running iOS 11 or later) using the built-in mechanism.

Is there a similar built-in facility available in macOS to record Mac screen?

Comment: A simple Google search for [screen recording macos](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=vaWjW5L7B8PksAWijrVQ&q=screen+recording+macos&btnK=Google+Search&oq=screen+recording+macos&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l2j0i22i30l7j0i22i10i30.6205.6205..6448...0.0..0.127.127.0j1......0....1j2..gws-wiz.Dvd8R3RgYpM) would have provided you the answer

Comment: @user3439894 - That comment is bordering on what's considered "unfriendly behavior" per the [Code of Conduct](https://apple.stackexchange.com/conduct).  Not flagging, but please keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in QuickTime Player.app in macOS to record screen.

Follow the instructions in the Apple support article, [Record your screen](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/quicktime-player/record-your-screen-qtp97b08e666/mac).

> 1. Open QuickTime Player app by going to Launchpad → Other or by searching for QuickTime in Spotlight.
> 2. Once the app is open, in the Menu bar go to File → New Screen Recording or alternatively use the keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. In the presented window as shown, click on the record button, then choose the recording type.
> 4. When you’re finished recording, click Stop in the menu bar.
> 5. Choose File → Save, then enter a name for the recording.
>
>    The recording is saved as an H.264 format QuickTime movie with an AAC audio track (if audio was selected).